# How to position divs on top of canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have the following html:

```
<body>
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"></input>
    <div id="backward" class="button"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border: 1px solid;"></canvas>
    <div id="forward" class="button"></div>
</body>
```

and the following css:

```
#canvas{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 50;
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

What other css do I need to position the backward div inside the left of the canvas element and the forward div inside the right of the canvas element?

Comment: Inside the left? Inside the right? What does that mean?

Comment: It's working just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/CMM32/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the div element with the ID "backward" to the left and the element with ID "forward" to the right you can use the properties "right" and "left". Like this:

```css
#backward{
    left: 10px;
}

#forward{
    right: 10px;
}
```

Then you can always increase and decrease if needed. And that me assuming that the divs are not to big from the start and that the actually fits. If not you can always add a size on the divs.